# Proving a modified Hall's marriage theorem where 2 women are paired with each man

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We are given a set $M$ of men and a set $W$ of women such that every subset of men likes a set of women at least twice its size (In other words if $A$ is a subset of men and $k(A)$ is the set of women liked by some man in $A$, then $|k(A)|\geq 2|A|$). Prove that to each man can be paired 2 women that he likes such that no woman will be paired to more than 1 man.

I've managed to prove by induction essentially all cases except the case where $|M|$ is even and there is a subset $A\subsetneq M$ with $k(A)=2|A|+1$ but there isn't a subset $A\subsetneq M$ such that $k(A)=2|A|$ (I've done so by mimicking the inductive proof of the normal marriage theorem). For this last case I can't seem to use induction, because if I consider $M/A$ then it is possible it has a subset $B$ that likes $2|B|-1$ women in $k(M/A)$, so I can't use the induction step on $M/A$ and $k(M/A)$.

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: @saulspatz I've updated the question to show my progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this doesn't use induction. Simply define a new set $M'$ which contains two clones of each man in $M$, with both of them having the same preferences as the original man in $M$. Then, applying Hall's theorem to $M', W$, you can match up $M'$ and $W$. Now pair each man in $M$ with the two women paired with his clones.